# New dialog in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

The following is the code in my application

```
$('.roster-contact').live('click', function () {
    $('#chat-area').dialog('open');
    .......
```

When i click on a second contact, it is using the previously opened dialog, but i 
    need to display a separate dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a plugin, dialogWrapper, that does exactly what you want. You can use it to dynamically create dialogs without the need to pre-define them on the page: http://code.google.com/p/dialogwrapper/#Simple_dialog

Here is my blog post on it: http://mostthingsweb.com/?p=356 (post is for version 2.0.4, currently at version 2.0.7)

[Download it here](http://code.google.com/p/dialogwrapper/downloads/list)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.roster-contact').live('click', function () {
    var div = $('<div>');
    div.dialog();
    .......
```

Comment: var div = $('<div>'); instead of var div = ('<div>');